# Should I flag "me too" answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, flagging

I am seeing a small issue with "me too"s on a few questions, especially common hardware that often has driver issues, like [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128116/slow-wireless-just-installed-12-04lts-via-cd). Should this be flagged, commented, or something else?

Comment: If the OP goes back and actually adds their hardware info you can help by editing the question to be hardware specific, that way they don't attract generic posts.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is the comment used to inform users that "Me too" is not a valid answer:

> If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

```
 If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.
```

These should be flagged as not real answers and deleted.