# Should really good/detailed "me too" answers have their content merged into the question?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, editing, flagging

Usually ["me too" answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3024/should-i-flag-me-too-answers) don't contribute much to working on the problem, but sometimes they do, as when they present details that are subtly different than (or more detailed than) what is provided by the OP. It seems to me that [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/141424/22949) may be an instance of a "me too" answer that gives sufficiently different detail from a logfile to be potentially useful in solving the problem.

Should I edit the detail into the original question (even though it's a significant number of lines) before flagging it? Or should I put the logfile excerpt on [Ubuntu PasteBin](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and edit the question to point to it, before flagging this answer? Or should I just flag it, without doing any of that? And what are some general guidelines that I should consider when making these decisions about similar but slightly different cases in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put a comment asking the OP if the `me too` bit applies or be absolutely sure it doesn't change the meaning of the question.

Then I'ld just edit it in.

Edits can be reverted if it turns out they changed the meaning of something.