# Is it possible for a deleted answer to be converted to a question?

Tags: discussion, support

This question was prompted in part by the content of [this one](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17210/me-too-post-or-partial-answer) which got me to wondering if the system allows this type of reassessment, either manually or automatically. And if so, what level of reputation or sequence of events is required to complete the process?

Comment: I think you can only either get the OP to post the question themselves (which might get difficult as you can't comment below deleted posts) or ask the question yourself if you are personally interested or think it would be a useful question.

Comment: @ByteCommander Difficult indeed. I am aware of those options. I guess I was just wondering if there were tools available that I was unaware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not automatically, no.

Comment: There is a manual method though? (Assuming high enough rep)

Comment: Yes, it's called copy and pasting ;)

Comment: I get that part. Is there any way to maintain the OP as the poster?

Comment: @ElderGeek not if they don't ask the question, no. Seems like that would open up abuse.

Comment: Makes sense. thanks